# Интересный способ объединения JS файлов с помощью PHP

Tags: php, css, javascript

Нашел интересный способ объединения JS файлов с помощью PHP, для уменьшения скорости загрузки сайта. Этот же способ можно применить и для CSS файлов.

```
readfile(jquery.js');
readfile(general.js');
readfile(jquery-ui.js');
readfile(page.js');

header('Content-type: text/javascript');
```

Метод еще не проверял, но думаю имеет право на жизнь. А что думаете Вы? Как можно улучшить данный кусок кода?

Comment: Будет ли вызов интерпретатора быстрее чистой отправки нескольких файлов сервером? И еще
1) заголовки должны отправляться первыми, поэтому сначала header()
2) очень неудобно при поиске ошибок из консоли искать строку и сам файл

Comment: Помимо неудобной отладки, это ещё и помешает браузеру кешировать скрипты.

Comment: Надо попробовать код встроится в страницу или нет.

Comment: Я бы не стал сильно минусов много у этого подхода.

Comment: @eprivalov1 встраивается, браузеру же все равно на расширение <script src="script.php">, просто сервер по правилам увидев *.php вызовет интерпретатор

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Улучшить его можно только выкинув и использовать инструменты созданные специально для объединения и минификации файлов, например [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) + [concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) + [uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify), а также [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) + [grunt-contrib-requirejs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs).

Почему? Всё просто, во-первых это статика и собирать её через php очень затратно. Помимо этого, на каждый хит, вы имеет 4-ре дисковые операции, что тоже не хорошо. Во-вторых, нет минификации.  Ну, а в-третьих, нет кеширования и даже если выставить нужные заголовки, это всё равно будет хуже, чем отдавать статику при помощи nginx, которые для этого и создан.

P.S. Такое решение можно использовать как временное, либо в процессе разработки, но на продакшн тащить его не стоит.

P.S.S. С `CSS` тоже самое, все уже давно используют препроцессоры  ([sass](http://sass-lang.com/), [less](http://lesscss.org/), [stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) и т.п.), ну и опять же grunt.